# Google sign in, How to get google userID server-side after user already signed in?

Tags: php, api, server-side, google-oauth

Hi first question ever on stack!

I'm used to Facebook Connect and I'm implementing Google Sign in to my site.
User can connect with their FB or Google+ Account (client side javascript API), I create a user profile in my database and store their fb UId or G+ UID. No problem!

Now when they come back... With facebook API I can easily use their php API to get the current user Id $facebook->getUser() so I can retrieve the user profile from the DB

With Google+ I can easily get the G+ UID Client-side with their javascript API (gapi.auth.authorize), but how to do the same on server-side without asking for offline access authorization?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways you can accomplish this.

If you have an authorization code (you don't need offline access to request 'code' response type), you can make a call to the token endpoint and obtain an id_token in the backchannel. Base64 decoding the token will give you the user_id. This method does not require you to verify the signature in the id_token because you are making a server-side call directly to a secure (TLS/HTTPS protected) Google handler.

Otherwise you can request 'id_token' response and then perform full id_token validation. This requires both checking the Google signature and ensuring that the id_token was issued to *your* application (match your client_id against the 'aud' parameter of the id_token).

This strategies are explained in more detail at: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#exchangecode (first method)
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatinganidtoken (second method).

The first method is easier to implement, and the second method is more efficient (requires no network round-trip).

Comment: first method: That means I'll need to keep the authorization code that is returned from the initial request in my DB?